# python bindings for android adb

Tags: python, c, binding, adb

i'm creating an automation framework in python for our android devices.
i've written a wrapper for adb commands by using Popen to run adb.
this is nice but i'de rather skip on the process creating for every call (many calls to adb)
So i thought about creating bindings for the C code (adb is in C).

As far as i understand there are 3 options:
1. compile adb as an SO and use ctypes.
2. create python extension using python.h and add adb source code to the compilation making a full python interface to the command.
3. doing the same like #2 using Cython.

Since i've never done it before, any recommendation for which method is better for my scenario ? consider performance and time to market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `c` bindings. Just use sockets to connect to the `adb` daemon from your python code https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/6755712

Comment: that's wasn't the question, but that's definitely the answer, even though it's got a downside which is any new action added to adb i will need to manually add once adb code is updated while binding to C i just recompile.10x for the code, didn't find it myself!